# SAPUI5 vertical alignment Radiobuttongroup

Tags: alignment, sapui5

Is there a way to create a radiobuttongroup with vertical alignment?

What I did is I created a verticalLayout around my radiobuttongroup shown in the picture below.

[image: Coding with Vertical Layout and Radiobuttongroup (two Columns)]

What I recieve is this:

[image: Result of the Radiobuttongroup]

What I want is this:

O a       O   b

How can I do that using a JavaScript-view in sapui5?

Comment: Just a suggestion, but it is much easier to read the question if you include the text of the code in your question, rather than a link to an image of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its the columns property which determins how many RadioButton Items will be shown in a single row.
Check the below link: [https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.commons.RadioButtonGroup.html#getColumns .](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.commons.RadioButtonGroup.html#getColumns)

For you Code, since there are only 2 items, you can set the columns property in the RadioButtonGroup to 2.

```
var oRBG = new sap.ui.commons.RadioButtonGroup({
            columns :2

        });
```

Comment: that's exactly what i needed. thank you very much :-)